# Rails routing error, but routes appear correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a routing error, but I think my routes are correct:

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"edit", :user_id=>#<Post id: 9, title: "Na Curva do Horizonte", content: "Eu na mesma minha opinião no pensamento vejo me ca...", created_at: "2013-01-12 20:41:57", updated_at: "2013-01-12 20:41:57", image_file_name: "iris_by_archang3lzz-d5k2i5l.jpg", image_content_type: "image/jpeg", image_file_size: 1101282, image_updated_at: "2013-01-12 20:41:56", user_id: 5>}
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

When I execute `rake routes`, the results are correct:

```
       user_posts GET    /user/:user_id/posts(.:format)              posts#index
                  POST   /user/:user_id/posts(.:format)              posts#create
    new_user_post GET    /user/:user_id/posts/new(.:format)          posts#new
   edit_user_post GET    /user/:user_id/posts/:id/edit(.:format)     posts#edit
        user_post GET    /user/:user_id/posts/:id(.:format)          posts#show
```

My routes are:

```
 resources :posts

  resources :user  do
    resources :posts,:comments
  end

  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end
```

and the link in error is:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_post_path(notice) %>
```

I don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to edit a *specific* post which belongs to a *specific* user, you need to pass in those two as parameters to that link, putting the parent first. Otherwise rails doesn't know which post you are about to edit.

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_post_path(@user, @post) %>
```

So all you seem to need is those two variables.

Read you rake routes carefully. It says:

```
/user/:user_id/posts/:id/edit(.:format)
```

So there you can see that you need `:user_id` as well as `:id`, which refers to the post. Giving the objects as parameters will be enough, rails is smart enough to figure out their ids and use them for the link.

Comment: Dont works, i pass the user but have this error: AbstractController::DoubleRenderError in PostsController#edit

Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".

Comment: The error message explains it all. Have a look at your postscontroller's edit method - it seems you are rendering/redirecting to something twice. Get rid of one instance.

Comment: So the problem now its in your controller action not in the routes

Comment: Yes, my controller have a redirect, thanks by the help, thanks.